# Disconnect a Remote Desktop session programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, remote-desktop, rdp

How do I disconnect a Remote Desktop session programmatically in a C# or C++ application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [WTSDisconnectSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383830.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could try running tsdiscon:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321705

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in C# to fetch the remote desktop connection pid    by using its name and then kill

```
   Process[] my = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc");
   int pid = my[0].Id;
   Process pro = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
   pro.Kill();
```